# C++ - Lua: get caller table name

Tags: c++, lua

How can i get in a c++ function the name of the table who calls it?

Here is the c++ sourcecode, i need to store objects in a c++ map and in lua tables, the c++ map->first is the same name of the table in lua.

see the function `static int move_to(lua_State* L)` i need to modify the lua table who calls that function.

**Test.cpp**

```
#include <lua.hpp>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Point{
    int x=0, y=0;
};

std::map<std::string, Point> points;

static int move_to(lua_State* L){
    int num_args=lua_gettop(L);
    if(num_args>=2){
        int new_x=lua_tonumber(L, 1);//first argument: x.
        int new_y=lua_tonumber(L, 2);//second argument: y.
        std::string name=???;//i need to get the name of the lua table who calls this function.
        lua_getglobal(L, name.c_str());
        lua_pushnumber(L, new_x);
        // modify point in the lua table.
        lua_setfield(L, -2, "x");// point.x=x
        lua_pushnumber(L, new_y);
        lua_setfield(L, -2, "y");// point.x=x
        // modify point in the c++ map.
        points.find(name)->second.x=new_x;
        points.find(name)->second.y=new_y;
    };
    return 0;
};

static int create_point(lua_State* L){
    int num_args=lua_gettop(L);
    if(num_args>=2){
        std::string name=lua_tostring(L, 1);//first argument: name.
        int x=lua_tonumber(L, 2);//second argument: x.
        int y=lua_tonumber(L, 3);//third argument: y.
        static const luaL_Reg functions[]={{ "move_to", move_to},{ NULL, NULL }};
        lua_createtable(L, 0, 4);
        luaL_setfuncs(L, functions, 0);
        lua_pushnumber(L, x); lua_setfield(L, -2, "x");// point.x=x
        lua_pushnumber(L, y); lua_setfield(L, -2, "y");// point.y=y
        lua_setglobal(L, name.c_str());
        points.insert(std::pair<std::string, Point>(name, Point()));// insert point in the c++ map.
    };
    return 0;
};


int main(){
    lua_State * L=luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaL_loadfile(L, "script.lua");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, create_point); lua_setglobal(L, "create_point");//Register create_point to L.
    lua_call(L, 0, 0);
    std::cout<<"c++: a.x: "<<points.find("a")->second.x<<", a.y: "<<points.find("a")->second.y<<std::endl;
    return 0;
};
```

Here is the lua script.

**Test.lua**

```
--           name, x, y
create_point("a", 10, 11)
print("lua: a.x: " .. a.x .. ", a.y: " .. a.y)
a.move_to(1,2)
print("lua: a.x: " .. a.x .. ", a.y: " .. a.y)
```

Comment: Please describe the problem you are having with this code more specifically, and what you expect the result to have been.

Comment: I have edited the question i hope that it the problem is more clear now, let me know i you do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i get in a c++ function the name of the table who calls it?

You can't get table's name, since values don't have names.
Just pass that table as first argument, the very much like **this** pointer in C++.
 Lua has special syntax to make it easy:

```
a:move_to(1,2)
```

Note the difference - colon is used instead of dot. That syntactic sugar is shorter equivalent to:

```
a.move_to(a,1,2)
```